# Uploading chunked files to s3 with php

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-s3, chunking, tmp

I have a php script where I store a file uploaded by the user in a tmp folder and then move it to s3. I also check if the emails they entered are valid in the database. I am using chunking so that large files can get uploaded to the server quickly. My post_max_size is 8M, however I am only able to upload files that are very small.

For example, If I upload a 7M file, I get an alert I set which says the file size is too large. This alert is only supposed to show if file size is >8M. If I upload a 1 KB file, it uploads the file successfully. Am I doing something incorrectly? I'm fairly new to php so I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` go hand in hand when handling file uploads. What is that value?

Comment: Not your current issue but your you are only using `mysqli` safely once. The rest of your code is open to SQL injections. The code around `bind values from $tags to the query` is correct. The rest of `mysqli` usage is not safe. Parameterize everywhere

Comment: @ZoliSzabó post_max_size is 8M and upload_max_filesize is 2M. However, even if I upload a file that is 8 KB I get the alert.

Comment: @user3783243 will do! any solutions for the current issue I'm facing?

Comment: Where's the code that fires the `alert`?

Comment: @user3783243 the alert is fired from the else statement in the ajax success function. I just have simple code for an alert modal in my html file. But it shouldn't be going into that else statement in the first place since if ($_FILES['file']['size'] <= ini_get('post_max_size') should be true in the php check (line 3).

Answer (score 0):

`ini_get('post_max_size')` can (and will) return human-friendly values. So you will end up comparing integer file size values with string values (`8M` in your case). And `9000 > '8M'`...

**UPDATE:**
There is no need to explicitly use the PHP configuration values `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize`, because:

1. in case of exceeding the `post_max_size` value, the `$_FILES` array will be empty, plus a warning will be generated, e.g.:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 3414 bytes exceeds the limit of 2048 bytes in Unknown on line 0

2. in case of exceeding the `upload_max_filesize` value, the corresponding `'error'` field(s) within the `$_FILES` array will contain the `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` value, e.g:

> array(1) { ["name"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "filename.ext" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" **["error"]=> int(1)** ["size"]=> int(0) } }

All the above mean that if there's a non-empty `$_FILES` array available and the value of the error field is `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`, you can be sure that the upload was successful and configuration values were also respected.

In your case this translates to the condition `if ($_FILES['file']['size'] <= ini_get('post_max_size')) ...` not only incorrect (comparing integer file sizes (e.g. `9000`) with possibly non-integer strings (e.g. `'8M'`)), but also not needed at all.

Comment: I changed it to '8M' but I am still getting the alert for files smaller than 8M.

Comment: Let me repeat what I wrote again: `ini_get('post_max_size')` will return in your case `'8M'` as-is. Not `8388608`. So you cannot compare integer values coming from `$_FILES['file']['size']` with the value from `ini_get('post_max_size')`, unless you previously convert the human-friendly value `'8M'` to the machine-friendly `8388608`. Otherwise the comparison is not correct.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. Should I use $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] to make the comparison with ini_get('post_max_size') then?

Comment: Ok so if I remove that if statement altogether, I should be good right? Because my first two if statements are basically checking that $_FILES array is not empty and upload error is ok.

Comment: Yes, `array_key_exists('file', $_FILES) && ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` is enough to make sure that file sizes are alright (and also to eliminate other upload error cases).

Comment: It's still not accepting all files under 8M. I made the changes you suggested

Comment: Which condition is failing?

Comment: `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` is the condition that failed.

Comment: What value does `$_FILES['file']['error']` contain?

Comment: The value is 1 when that condition fails

Comment: Value `1` is `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` meaning "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini". Are you 100% sure the `upload_max_filesize` config value is larger than the size of the file you want to upload?

Comment: Nevermind, I was being stupid lol. It's working, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how relevant this may be, but I noticed that you haven't specified anywhere that the type of the data is "multipart/form-data". I've always been under the impression that a file upload won't work correctly unless this is specified.

Also not related per se but I see you're using jQuery. I recommend moving away from that and using the native fetch API. It's a cleaner and more modern solution.

Comment: I am using multipart/form-data in my HTML form code. I haven't included that code because it's not super relevant to the issue I'm having right now.